# How to echo multi-line output from captured command?

Tags: git, bash, shell

I would like to echo the output from a command in the same format that it would output when I run a command on the terminal, but for some reason, using echo seems to eliminate newlines.

Example:

```sh
$ OUTPUT=$(git status)
$ echo $OUTPUT
 # On branch feature_install # Untracked files: # (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed) # # install/ nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

But this should have printed:

```sh
$ git status
# On branch feature_install
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   install/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Additionally, can color be maintained in the parsed output? (Using echo, color was not maintained)

Comment: The color was never there.  git noticed that the output was not a tty and did not print the escape codes for color.

Comment: Try `IFS='\n'` before your OUTPUT-line and see if it helps.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17732/where-has-the-trailing-newline-char-gone-from-my-command-substitution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use double quotes, the newlines will be maintained:

```
echo "$OUTPUT"
```

As to the color: git does not output color codes if the output is not a tty.  To force the color codes, you can do:

```
OUTPUT=$( GIT_PAGER_IN_USE=true git status )
```